# How to print pdf file with excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

Hi all i need to print pdf files from one folder after printing the file i need move that file into another folder. My system is x86 bit so someone please help me on this issue

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String _
    , ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Sub Auto_print()

Dim lstFile As String
Dim lstDir As String
Dim i As Long

lstDir = "C:" & VBA.Environ("homepath") & "\Desktop\auto\"
lstFile = VBA.Dir(lstDir & "*.pdf")

Do While VBA.Len(lstFile) > 0
    i = FindWindow("XLMAIN", Application.Caption)
   ShellExecute i, "print", lstFile, vbNullString, vbNullString, 10
    lstFile = VBA.Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to move file and call it in your code after printing.

```
i = FindWindow("XLMAIN", Application.Caption)
ShellExecute i, "print", lstFile, vbNullString, vbNullString, 10
MoveFile lstFile
lstFile = VBA.Dir
```

replace `Destination Folder\` with actual path where you need to move the files.

```
Private Function MoveFile(strSource As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fso.MoveFile source:=strSource, Destination:="Destination Folder\" & Right(strSource, Len(strSource) - InStrRev(strSource, "\"))
End Function
```

Comment: could you please help me to know, which .dll is help me to print the file?

Comment: where did you receive the error. what was the input?